# Zend session initiation

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I have the following code in my zend application bootstrap file

```
protected function _initSessionId() {
    $this->bootstrap( 'session' );
    $opts = $this->getOptions();
    $cache = $this->bootstrap( 'cachemanager' )
    ->getResource( 'cachemanager' )
    ->getCache( 'memcached' );
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache( $cache );

    Zend_Registry::set( 'cache', $cache );
    $defaultNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    if ( !isset( $defaultNamespace->initialized ) ) {
        Zend_Session::regenerateId();
        $defaultNamespace->initialized = true;
    }
}
```

I want to know what the line `$this->bootstrap('session')` actually does. Which class/function does it instantiate and call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to bootstrap a *resource*

`bootstrap(<resource_name>)` tells to Zend_Bootstrap to init the specified resource before continue. Usually is used for init required dependencies before init the actual `resource`

The resource bootstrap can be declared in two ways.

A PHP method in the `Bootstrap` class.

```
function _init<Resource_name>() { ... }
```

Or in the `ini` file

```
resources.<resource_name>
```

in the last case (`ini` file) a class extending from `Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract` must be declared with the code for init the resource.

### Session resource bootstrap

For the concrete case of `bootstrap('session')` by default use the `init()` method declared in `Zend_Application_Resource_Session`

Comment: Thanks for answering. For the case of 1$this->bootstrap('session');`, which class will be loaded. I am guessing Zend_Session. Also the function defined as _initSessionId no class with name SessionId is necessary, correct?

Comment: Yes. I saw that later. Had to wait a minute to mark as answered though. Thanks.