# Zend configuation file not linking correctly

Tags: zend-framework, ini

I am new to the Zend framework and struggling to understand how the Zend .ini file configuration works. There seems to be very little documentation/tutorial regarding it.

I am trying to set up a system path for my images. I want to store images in the following folder:

```
C:\Dev\example_site\httpdocs\ep\resource\modelling_photos
```

I have tried to store the path to this folder in a .ini file but it did not link correctly. I suspect that I am still confused about how the .ini format works.

Does anyone know any good tutorials on this issue? For example, in what is shown below, what does the code on the left mean as opposed to the code on the right:

```
assets.asset.modelling_photos.path = resource/modelling_photos/%s-%s.%s
assets.asset.modelling_photos.base = local
```

Comment: If you want the users to be able to see the photos, it might be easier to put them under /public_html/img/modelling_photos/.  Afterwards, they can be accessed via $this->baseUrl().'/img/modelling_photos' (ZF1)

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the config options from the getOptions method of Bootstrap or create a custom resource loader that is more close to a DI system

[Zend session initiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902528/zend-session-initiation/15902713#15902713)